# I'm trying to run init 0 on fish shell but i get weird error

Tags: shell, fish

I was trying to run `$init 0` and then this was the response by the fish shell. I was tweaking some part today but don't know what I might have messed up during the process. 
`source: Error encountered while sourcing file “0/functions/git/vcs.git.present.fish”:`

Comment: This is not a very good question: "I changed something and now something broke: what's wrong?" Please read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: You should always specify the versions of all relevant software and the OS you're using. Also, whether you have any non-standard extensions installed (e.g., OMF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a function called `init` (from oh-my-fish or something?), and "0" is an invalid argument for that.

Use `command init` if you want to refer to the command.

Comment: You can confirm @faho's hypothesis by running `type init`. If it is, as seems likely,  a function that will show you where it came from and its definition.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. There was an `init.fish` function which overrode the init command because I had the `vcs` plugin installed. Thank you!